# Understanding vector spherical harmonics

Tags: general-relativity, spherical-harmonics

I am studying [this](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.108.1063) classical paper by Regge and Wheeler *Stability of a Schwarzschild singularity*.

In the second page they introduce their formalism with spherical harmonics and generalization thereof. In particular in eqns. (7) and (8), they introduce vector spherical harmonics, with the definitions:

$$\psi^M_{L,\mu}\propto \partial_\mu Y_l^M \quad \phi_{L,\mu}^M\propto \epsilon_\mu^\nu \partial_\nu Y_L^M$$

where $\mu,\nu=\{\theta,\phi\}$ and $\epsilon_\theta^\theta=\epsilon_\phi^\phi=0$, $\epsilon_\theta^\phi = -\dfrac{1}{\sin\theta}$ and $\epsilon_\phi^\theta=\sin\theta$.

I do not understand how are vectors decomposed into their components wrt these harmonics.

Comment: For an introduction to vector spherical harmonics see, for example,
https://www.fisica.unam.mx/personales/rbarrera/pdf/pub/int/29-EuroJP-6-287-85.pdf

Comment: "Mathematical Physics" by Arfken & Weber may discuss vector spherical harmonics but I'd have to check. After vector spherical harmonics there is tensorial spherical harmonics but I cannot link to any resources regarding this topic at the moment.

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/708276/226902